# Evaluating a strange integral...

Tags: calculus, integration

I was given this integral by a friend and have been unable to evaluate it. He said it is easily possible to do it by hand (no calculator or computational aids necessary)

$$\int_{0}^{1} \mathrm{frac}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\cdot\mathrm{frac}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)dx $$

frac is a function that returns the fractional part of x. I attempted to "simplify" this to x-floor(x), but was still unable to get anywhere.

He also gave me a hint that it involves the euler mascheroni constant. I looked at the integral representation of it but was unable to make any progress

Comment: This integral and many similar integrals have been popularized in Ovidiu Furdui's interesting book (you can find it in some sample free pages in a link at the bottom): http://www.springer.com/us/book/9781461467618?token=prtst0416p

Comment: $\mathrm{frac}\left(\cdots\right)$ and $\mathrm{floor}\left(\cdots\right)$ are usually written as $\left\{\cdots\right\}$ and $\left\lfloor\cdots\right\rfloor$, respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making the variable change, $u = 1-x,$ we have

$$\int_{1/2}^1 \left\{\frac{1}{x} \right\}\left\{\frac{1}{1-x} \right\}  \, dx  = \int_{0}^{1/2} \left\{\frac{1}{1-u} \right\}\left\{\frac{1}{u} \right\}  \, du.  $$

Hence,

$$\int_0^1 \left\{\frac{1}{x} \right\}\left\{\frac{1}{1-x} \right\}  \, dx = 2\int_0^{1/2} \left\{\frac{1}{x} \right\}\left\{\frac{1}{1-x} \right\}  \, dx \\ = 2\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k =2}^n \int_{1/(k+1)}^{1/k} \left\{\frac{1}{x} \right\}\left\{\frac{1}{1-x} \right\}  \, dx. $$

For $1/(k+1) < x < 1/k$ we have $k < 1/x < k+1$ and $1 + 1/k < 1/(1-x) < 1 + 1/(k-1)$.

Hence, for $k \geqslant 2$,

$$\left\{\frac{1}{x} \right\} = \frac{1}{x} - k, \\ \left\{\frac{1}{1-x} \right\} = \frac{1}{1-x} - 1,$$

and

$$\int_0^1 \left\{\frac{1}{x} \right\}\left\{\frac{1}{1-x} \right\}  \, dx = 2\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k =2}^n \int_{1/(k+1)}^{1/k} \left(\frac{1}{x}-k \right) \left(\frac{1}{1-x} -1\right)  \, dx.$$

Proceeding,

$$\begin{align}\int_{1/(k+1)}^{1/k} \left(\frac{1}{x}-k \right) \left(\frac{1}{1-x} -1\right)  \, dx &= \int_{1/(k+1)}^{1/k} \left(\frac{1-kx}{1-x} \right) \, dx \\ &=\int_{1/(k+1)}^{1/k} \left(\frac{(1-k) + k(1-x)}{1-x} \right) \, dx \\ &= [(k-1) \log(1-x) +kx]_{1/(k+1)}^{1/k}  \\ &= (k-1) \log \frac{k-1}{k} - (k-1)\log \frac{k}{k+1} +\frac{1}{k+1} \\ &= k\log \frac{k+1}{k} - (k-1) \log \frac{k}{k-1} - [\log(k+1) - \log k] + \frac{1}{k+1}\end{align}$$

Summing, we get

$$\begin{align}\sum_{k =2}^n \int_{1/(k+1)}^{1/k} \left(\frac{1}{x}-k \right) \left(\frac{1}{1-x} -1\right)  \, dx  &= \sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{k+1} -\log(n+1) + n \log \frac{n+1}{n} \\ &= -\frac{3}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{k} - \log(n+1) + \log \left[\left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n \right]\end{align}.$$

Taking the limit as $n \to \infty$ we find

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k =2}^n \int_{1/(k+1)}^{1/k} \left(\frac{1}{x}-k \right) \left(\frac{1}{1-x} -1\right)  \, dx = -\frac{1}{2} + \gamma ,$$

and

$$\int_0^1 \left\{\frac{1}{x} \right\}\left\{\frac{1}{1-x} \right\}  \, dx = -1 + 2\gamma.$$

Comment: Is {} common to denote frac(x)? Also, I am confused about how you went from step 1 to step 2 and step 2 to step 3. Could you explain the logic and the motivation for writing it as a summation?  How do you realize the integral is symmetric about x=0.5 without graphing it?

Comment: Yes that is the notation for frac.  Just added some more detail

Comment: We see the integral is symmetric by using the substitution $u = 1-x$.

Comment: We write it as a sum over intervals $[1/(k+1),1/k]$ because we can identify the fractional part of $1/x$ and $1/(1-x)$ easily as I show.  Note that on the integration interval $[0,1/2]$ we also know that $1/(1-x)$ is between $1$ and $2$ so the fractional part is just $1/(1-x) - 1$.